# Is it possible to write a script to uncheck the turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible) checkbox

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-11, control-panel

Whenever I use remote desktop to get into my computer at work, I always have to go to the:

> control panel -> ease of access center -> make the computer easier to see

…and I need to **uncheck** the checkbox named "Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible) checkbox in order for me to be able to drag the scrollbar in excel and have the page update while I drag.

Is there a way to write a script (batch or powershell) to uncheck that checkbox?

Comment: find out which registry key changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to write a script (batch or powershell) to uncheck that checkbox?*
>
> ---
>
> - **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**
>
> ```
> Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -Name UserPreferencesMask -Value ([byte[]](0x90,0x12,0x03,0x80,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00))
> ```
>
> ---
>
> - **[bath](/questions/tagged/bath)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**
>
> ```bash
> @echo off
>
> set "_hKey="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v UserPreferencesMask" 
>
> reg query %_hKey% | find "%_vhex%" >nul || reg add %_hKey% /t Reg_Binary /d "9E2C078010000000" /f
> ```
>
> ---
>
> - **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**
>
> ```
> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v UserPreferencesMask /t REG_BINARY /d "9E2C078010000000" /f
> ```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote this answer, but it's exactly what I was looking for. My particular UserPreferencesMask was slightly different, but I just modified this script to suit my setup. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you and relax, know that I can't upvote this answer either d;)

Answer (score 0):

One [post](https://www.freelists.org/post/thin/Anyone-know-if-their-is-a-GPO-or-registry-key-for-Turn-off-all-unecessary-animations,12)
lists these registry settings:

> there are 2 registry values involved:
>
> `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask`
>
> This is a reg_binary value. Change this value from `9E 2C 07 80 12 00 00 00` to `9E 2C 07 80 10 00 00 00`.
>
> `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\VisualFxSetting`
>
> The `VisualEffects` key doesn't exist by default. There are a bunch of
> values that can be defined under here but the only one that really
> matters is VisualFxSettings. Set this to `2` to disable a lot of the
> animations and also to tick "Turn off all unnecessary animations (when
> possible)" .

Take care when updating the registry.